# The "XsltListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Unable to find the specified file

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, blog

I have a SharePoint Online Site Classic team site template. I also have 1 blogs site as subsite underneath it. On top level site i am using content query webpart to publish blog items from blogs subsite.

Now i am trying to assign users to add comments on the posts. To do that i went to blogs site --> Site Contents--> Comments--> Lists Settings-->Permissions for this list.

On that page i broke inheritance and assigned visitors group a contribute access.

When i did that xslt webpart on top level site bombed. It triggered following error.

The "XsltListViewWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Unable to find the specified file.

I dont know why this is happening, I have implemented this in SharePoint 2013 onprem no problem. Why is Sp online acting the way it is.

Any way to mitigate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case here's what I found:

- Microsoft introduced a change that causes an error when clicking links to items displayed the "Content Query" web parts we use to show cross-site news and announcements on our Intranet pages
- This error can occur when the blog's Comments list has unique permissions to enable people to post comments but not edit news blog content).  It may also occur if there are other list-level unique permissions on the Blog Site.
- In our case, removing the unique permissions from the Comments lists fixes the error, but of course disables the ability for viewers to comment. The "Like" feature is unaffected and remains.[image: Removing Unique Permissions from the Comments List Fixes issues for us]

Comment: FYI -  Microsoft Issued a notice about this issue in the Office 365 Administration Portal:  "We're in the process of preparing a hotfix to the affected environment, and we expect the deployment to complete within two to three weeks. We'll provide updates on the status of this deployment as it progresses."

Comment: how long ago was that.

Comment: Do you have documentation on that notice,can you share that over to me.